# Laravel and Infinite Scroll not showing

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4

I'm having Trouble implementing Infinity Scroll into my laravel site.

In Google Chrome Dev log there is no errors,

but it doesn't work when I go into my browse grid.

In just displays a standard Laravel grid with pagination links at the bottom

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/jquery.infinitescroll.js') }}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#boxes').infinitescroll({
    navSelector     : ".paginate",
    nextSelector    : ".paginate a:last",
    itemSelector    : ".box",
    debug           : false,
    dataType        : 'html',
    path: function(index) {
        return "?page=" + index;
    }
}, function(newElements, data, url){

    var $newElems = $( newElements );
    $('#boxes').masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true);

});
});
</script>
```

Laravel Blade

```
    <div id="boxes" class="browse-grid">    
        @if ( ! $data->isEmpty())
            @foreach($data as $k => $r)
                   <figure class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-6" >
                   <div class="img-container">
                    </div>        
                </figure>

            @endforeach

        @else
            <div><h3 class="reviews-not-released"> {{ trans('main.no results') }}</h3></div>
        @endif

    </div> 
    {{ $data->appends(array())->links() }}
```

I copied the code from
[Laravel and Infinite Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487576/laravel-and-infinite-scroll)

But infinity scroll just doesn't launch for me.  My Pagination looks like this.

```
 <div class="row pagination-top">      <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=2">2</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=3">3</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=4">4</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=5">5</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=6">6</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=7">7</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=8">8</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=9">9</a></li><li><a href="http://test123.com/agents?page=2">&raquo;</a></li> </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but wanted to help you out if you're still looking for solution for this or if anyone else has a problem with this.

For me what helped,  I simply changed

```
$('#boxes').infinitescroll({
```

to:

```
$('.pagination').infinitescroll({
```

Though in the end I went with jscroll instead of infinite scroll, found it lots better myself. same change there (taken from example in the link you provided):

```
$('.scroll').jscroll({
```

to:
    $('.pagination').jscroll({

I just spent two days figuring this out and finally got it to work, hope that helps someone in need!