# Laravel pagination using infinite scroll

Tags: ajax, laravel, pagination, infinite-scroll

Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction on how to implement an infinite scroll in Laravel?

I'm familiar with Laravel's pagination tool and I'm also familiar with Javascript.

I just can't figure out what should i send via ajax to my controller?

By that i mean what url parameters and how would that dynamically change on scrolling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's one answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487576/laravel-and-infinite-scroll

Comment: @Kryten ok thanks, i'll give that a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not have to send via ajax something special
just grab via JS the id of last post which already have been loaded and perform ajax.get to `http://example.com/foo/100500`
catch id in routes.php something like this `Route::get('foo/{id}', 'BazController@bar'`
then perform any logic in your controller as you wish just considering the id
for example select from database where id between id and id+20

### **UPDATED**

considering @ugochimbo 's question

Let's say when we GET our page first time, we obtain something like

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="post-30">Lorem impum dolor</div>
    <div id="post-29">Lorem impum dolor</div>
    <div id="post-28">Lorem impum dolor</div>
</div>
```

An event is happened e.g. ( scrollTop is more than some px )

Then we execute something like

> Hey, jQuery! Gimme "id" of the last child of the #container //it will
>   be "post-28"

Considering the id, we perform an ajax query to a server.

I assume that for the simpliest implementation of infinity scrolling, we have to know just the "id" on the client side, nothing else.
Of course, in any real cases there is also a bunch of additional information, such as DESC or ASC or whatever else. It's all up to you.

Let's say we obtained on the server side via ajax query

```
{lastLoadedPostId: 'post-28', order: 'DESC', postsPerQuery: 3}
```

Of course, we have to make some preparations e.g. Cut "post-" from "lastLoadedPostId" etc

Then we ask our database

> Hey, database! Gimme 3 posts, that have id less than 28, in desc order

If nonIncremental identificators are used in your database, and you obtain on the server side

> {lastLoadedPostId: 'qwertyuid', order: 'DESC', postsPerQuery: 3}

In that case you should perform one extra query to database

> Hey, database! Tell me when "qwertyuid" was created
>
> Hey, database! Gimme 3 posts that were created earlier than "timestamp
>   of qwertyuid"

For this purpose you may use commands like LIMIT, OFFSET or whatever your database provided, but it's already other question

Comment: So basically what your saying is that i should save (keep track) of the last id i loaded and allays increment that, right?

Comment: i mean you should keep track id of the last loaded post _in your frontend only_

Comment: You are assuming the id's are incremented by 1... what if some records have been deleted (not soft delete) or for some reason one decides using a uuid or the likes which are not incremental ?